# wordpress misses styling and images on live server

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is my first wordpress site to deal. It uses bigbang theme and it works great on my development machine (localhost) but when it is live the following are missing: logo, background image and the basic styling.

I checked the source of both pages as output and saw the that the  is blank for the logo. It is generated by the following snippnet:

```
<img src="<?php echo of_get_option(BRANKIC_VAR_PREFIX."logo"); ?>" alt="<?php brankic_titles(); ?>" />
```

In local machine, it does produce the correct value. In the live server, src is ''.

I can only imagine the same for the background image and the fact that the size became 100% wide in live server is related to it.

Anyone idea where the link is broken? All the outputted JS and CSS sources/links are correctly produced. My servers are running the same PHP if that should matter.

Comment: If it's not returning anything I would check the theme settings where the logo is configured and make sure the image is set.

Comment: thanks APAD. I am lost why it is working like a charm in development mentions. if i set the values are set manually, it works fine but it needs to be dynamic. Let me look if the settings in my live server are been saved tho.